# Sharing an unsaved image

Tags: android, image, data-sharing

I want to share an image which is fresh created and therefore unsaved. It's stored in a `Bitmap` object. In the [send binary content](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content) article you need to have an URI to the image:
`shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);`

But is it somehow possible to share the image without saving it first?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yourBitmapObj.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/jpeg");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bos.toByteArray());
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send to"));
```

But if you want to share via popular apps, like Instagram, as I know they are trying to parse `Uri` but not getting the `ByteArray`, and you will receive exceptions from apps.